# Listview with text set from Html string and image issue

Tags: android, html, android-listview

I have custom listview with text and image , each row text retrieved from html string in string.xml ,

so each row must show text and image , but when i run the app it doesn't show the html tags, its get the text which stored in string.xml and show it in each row but without html tags effect , also the images not showing in each row

how we can get it to finally showing  list rows contain text with html tags and image probably.

any advice will be highly appreciated .

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
     ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lis);
     String[] textEntries = {getString(R.string.day1),getString(R.string.day2), 
                             getString(R.string.day3),getString(R.string.day4),
                             getString(R.string.day5)};

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, textEntries);
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Adapter class

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Activity context;
private final String[] textEntries;
Typeface tf;
static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView text;
    public ImageView image;
    }     
public MyAdapter(Activity context, String[] textEntries) {
    super(context, R.layout.row, textEntries);
    this.context = context;
    this.textEntries = textEntries;
    tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"BFantezy.ttf");
    }                                                   
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
      rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
      ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
      viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_label);
      viewHolder.image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_image);
      viewHolder.text.setTypeface(FontFactory.getBFantezy(getContext()));
      rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
      }     
     ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
     String s = textEntries[position];
     holder.text.setText(s);

if ( s.startsWith("day1")) {
    holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.a); 
    }                       
if ( s.startsWith("day2")) {
    holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.b); 
    }       
if ( s.startsWith("day3")) {
    holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.c); 
    }                       
if ( s.startsWith("day4")) {
    holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.d); 
    }       
if ( s.startsWith("day5")) {
    holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.e); 
    }                       
return rowView;  
}
}
```